# How to use spatie / laravel-multitenancy with single database?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I want to convert my existing app to multi-tenant and don't want to use multiple databases. just read that the given package is allowing that.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy

I have read the single database documentation here: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/installation/using-a-single-database

But what's next ??

Let's say right now users are storing into users' tables, and by using this package I want to store users tenant-specific.

I don't found the real example anywhere. so better if anyone already implemented Spatie Multi-tenant by using a single Database, please help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Although *spatie/laravel-multitenancy* supporting single databases, *it doesn't come with query scopes* (and seems like there are no plans to add them, as you can see here: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/issues/124), so you would need to create them manually.

So, you need to:

- add the tenant_id to your tenant-specific tables
- add an observer to save the tenant_id when creating a new register in the table
- add a global query scope to always filter the data using the current tenant id

You can see something similar in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCiNqboYFVQ

The difference is that you will use the current tenant returned by *spatie/laravel-multitenancy* instead of the logged user id to get the tenant data.

If you want a package that already brings the query scopes ready to use, you may try Tenancy for Laravel: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/single-database-tenancy

Or, if your application has a very simple multi-tenancy strategy (for example, the tenant is the logged user or his team) you can just create some query scopes without the need to use packages, exactly as the video above teaches, as it is much more simple to identify the tenant by the user_id or team_id, even in terminal commands and queue jobs (but seems that is not your case, as you need the users to belongs to a tenant).

I hope it helps you to select the correct package and strategy for your project.

Comment: Hii,

Thanks for informing me about this package, I also have tried but seems it's missing the documentations too.

I have created tenant table and added related trait to users table.

Now while initializing the tenancy i', facing errors.


If anyone can share the single DB example with given package, that would be better.

Thanks

Comment: @tiago silva pereira your answer is the correct one. There is no simple answer to multi-tenancy using a single database but you've summized the situation perfectly.